# Puma configuration file precedence

Tags: ruby, puma

I'd like to take advantage of Puma's automatic loading of environment-specific config (i.e. `config/puma/<environment>.rb`) but I'd like to have some common (to all environments) config as well. At the moment I'm using the undocumented `_load_from` Puma DSL to pull in `config/puma.rb` from `config/puma/<environment>.rb` but I wonder if there's a better way to do it. Has anyone else tackled this problem and what approach did you take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Future Mike here with almost a year more of Ruby experience. Looking at the Configuration#load method, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward of accomplishing this. It will choose the environment-based config file if one exists, falling back on the global config file. evanphx [added](https://github.com/puma/puma/commit/f788af0c8f7993899e35994d9c63dce4dd6de299) a public DSL#load DSL in February that does what you're trying to do with _load_from, so that might be the best route.

Comment: we’re you able to get the `#load` to work? It seems like that does something different and doesn’t work the same as the private method you used.